# How to autopopulate new field in models' existing objects with unique values in Django?

Tags: django

I have added new field called slug which need to be unique. It is already existing project.

During migrations Django asks what value should be used to fill already created objects. However any string will cause a conflict as value will not be unique.

I was planning to fill the slug field with values from other field of this model namely username.

Question: How can I populate above slug field (with unique = True) during migrations with unique values. Or maybe there is another way around that.

Thanks

Comment: I think blank=True will be enough. Let me know.

Comment: It does. Thanks. :)